# Combine two XMLDocuments rss

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I've got two rss feeds I would like to merge together to make one. I've actually managed to merge the two feeds together and place the items in correct place - however the data in each attribute, i.e. title contains title+link+description+author+pubDate - and that repeats for link, description, author and pubdate. Can someone help me dubug it please?

```
    Object rssData = new object();
    Cms.UI.CommonUI.ApplicationAPI AppAPI = new Cms.UI.CommonUI.ApplicationAPI();
    rssData = AppAPI.ecmRssSummary(50, true, "DateCreated", 0, "");

    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; 

    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDocument.LoadXml(rssData.ToString());


    //************************************************************
    // Obtain 5 data items from second list

    Object rssData1 = new object();
    Cms.UI.CommonUI.ApplicationAPI AppAPI1 = new Cms.UI.CommonUI.ApplicationAPI();
    rssData1 = AppAPI1.ecmRssSummary(60, true, "DateCreated", 5, "");

    XmlDocument xmlDocument1 = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDocument1.LoadXml(rssData1.ToString());


    XmlNodeList nl = xmlDocument1.SelectNodes("/rss/channel");
    XmlNode root = nl[0]; //do I need this line?

    foreach (XmlNode xnode1 in root.ChildNodes)
    {
        string title = xnode1.InnerText;
        string link = xnode1.InnerText;
        string desc = xnode1.InnerText;
        string auth = xnode1.InnerText;
        string pdate = xnode1.InnerText;

        //Merge new nodes

        node = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "item", null);
        //node.InnerText = "this is new node";

        //create title node
        XmlNode nodeTitle = xmlDocument.CreateElement("title");
        nodeTitle.InnerText = title;

        //create Link node
        XmlNode nodeLink = xmlDocument.CreateElement("link");
        nodeLink.InnerText = link;

        XmlNode nodeDesc = xmlDocument.CreateElement("description");
        nodeDesc.InnerText = desc;

        XmlNode nodeAuthor = xmlDocument.CreateElement("author");
        nodeAuthor.InnerText = auth;

        XmlNode nodepubDate = xmlDocument.CreateElement("pubDate");
        nodepubDate.InnerText = pdate;


        //add to parent node
        node.AppendChild(nodeTitle);
        node.AppendChild(nodeLink);
        node.AppendChild(nodeDesc);
        node.AppendChild(nodeAuthor);
        node.AppendChild(nodepubDate);

        //add to elements collection
        //xmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(node);
        xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/rss/channel")[0].AppendChild(node);
    }

    //********************************************

    xmlDocument.Save(Response.Output);
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is when I define the values of the variable: string title = xnode1.InnerText; - cant figure out how to get just the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you rightly suspected, the problem is here:

```
string title = xnode1.InnerText;
string link = xnode1.InnerText;
string desc = xnode1.InnerText;
string auth = xnode1.InnerText;
string pdate = xnode1.InnerText;
```

No wonder that

> the data in each attribute, i.e. title contains
>   title+link+description+author+pubDate - and that repeats for link,
>   description, author and pubdate.

You need to read the values of specific *subelements* of each node. Probably something like:

```
string title = xnode1["title"].InnerText;
```

etc.

See http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/ for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Konrad's answer is clear, but it might not work if there's nested tags within the title tag.

Say, `<title> TEXT <tag1>  OTHER_TEXT </tag1></title>`
On my computer, it will return you a concatenation of TEXT and OTHER_TEXT.

This should work:

```
string title = xnode1["title"].FirstChild.Value;
```

FirstChild will get you the *TEXT* no matter whether there is other tags with the title or not.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought RSS is a standardized format (and hence `title` element would not be expected to contain nested tags)